# Natural deduction proof without any predicate

Tags: predicate-logic, natural-deduction

I am gaving trouble proving a natural deduction proof when there is no predicate given. Only conclusion is given. I understand the rules of elimnations, inclusions, IPs and others but I having trouble applying them when no predicate is given. The question is:
$$ \vdash P(a) \to \forall x(P(x) \lor \lnot(x = a))$$

Also can anyone suggest me good websites to check my proofs and practice them.  I usually use https://proofs.openlogicproject.org but in this question it is showing that its not well formed.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: I tried assuming the negation of the conclusion and solving but the thing is without any given predicate I have never proved anything before and I tried to find that in our lectures but it was helpless.